What is inside the SPIKE Essential battery?
What is inside the 45345 SPIKE Essential battery?


This battery was glued when assembled, and it can only be opened destructively. The best way seems to be cutting with a knife around the seam to break all of the tabs that are glued in place.
Here's how it looks with the top removed:

The guts include two LiPo cells in series to give us the 7.3V nominal voltage.

The two cells are taped together with a charging circuit.
We can see on the cells that they each have a 2.44Wh capacity at a nominal voltage of 3.65V:

Here's a photo of the board with the connector:

And the back of the board showing the protection circuitry and cell connection points:

There is some additional information about this battery in TLG's official test report. That document includes a few photos of the components as well:

The materials safety datasheet (MSDS) may also be of interest. Both the testing document and the MSDS come from TLG's battery documentation.
